# How can I programmatically know when someone sends me Bitcoins?

Tags: development, bitcoind

I'm trying to set up a software system and part of it is knowing when someone sends Bitcoins to me automatically. I'm using [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), if that matters to anyone.

Comment: You should try giving more details in your question - will you be using a single address, or generate then on the fly and use them only once? Are you planning on running bitcoind somewhere, or want to have a standalone application? The more you tell us about the constrains of your system the better the community can help you with a solution that is tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BlockChain.info provides a push notification API:
 - http://blockchain.info/api_websocket

Comment: That looks very good. Is there also a quick way to take this information to see how many verifications it has?

Comment: Is it possible to do on my own? I mean how does blockchain.info get the info?

Comment: The BlockChain.info api looks cool but what if we want to use TestNet to test? Can we run a service like this on our own box? I was thinking of having a loop polling but wanted to know if there are any better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could poll the Block Explorer for balance of any Bitcoin address. For example, you can see the page of [the address that appeared in the Genesis Block](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa).